# Catch mailto links in WebView

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

Is there a method to this madness?  I am trying to build a browser app for a kiosk that restrict much need for running additional applications and simply stay within one website.

I research and found `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` should work for what I want, but how do I start filtering URI schemes (`mailto://`, `irc://`, etc.)? Thanks!

Comment: didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame is already doing a good job of keeping my webview to stay within the range I specify.  Is there a way to make this more robust to check against URI scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're implementing a WebView in your application to browse the web, right?
If yes, look into the [WebPolicyDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebPolicyDelegate_Protocol/) reference.
Especially the following delegate might be of interest:

```
               - (void)webView:(WebView *)webView 
decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation 
                       request:(NSURLRequest *)request 
                  newFrameName:(NSString *)frameName 
              decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
```

Using the above delegate, you can validate any request, including `mailto` requests.
Quick example how to detect the URL scheme and decide wether to block:

```
NSLog(@"Request URL scheme = %@",[[request URL] scheme]);
if([[[request URL] scheme]isEqualToString:@"mailto"])
{
    [listener ignore]; // Block Request
} 
else 
{
    [listener use]; // Allow Request
}
```